# Unzip Contents Based On Wildcard Negative Matching

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, wildcard, unzip

I have the following folder contents in a zip archive:

```
ca_ES
cs_CZ
da_DK
de_CH
de_DE
el_GR
en_GB
es_ES
fi_FI
fr_FR
gl_ES
it_IT
lv_LV
mt_MT
nb_NO
nl_NL
pt_PT
ro_RO
sk_SK
sl_SI
sq_AL
sv_SE
tr_TR
vi_VN
get-new-strings.sh
lang_check.php
lang_check.txt
language_list.txt
```

I am unzipping the file using this command where I *exclude* directories and files I do not want:

```
unzip -q ${ZIP_FILE} -x ${FOLDER_PATH}/documentation/* ${FOLDER_PATH}/library/pdf/help/* ${FOLDER_PATH}/library/pdf/samples/*
```

Now I am trying to exclude ALL files and folders in the above directory *except* the directories `en_GB` and `es_ES`.

I tried the following after reading [this](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/wildcards.html):

```
unzip -q ${ZIP_FILE} -x ${FOLDER_PATH}/documentation/* ${FOLDER_PATH}/library/pdf/help/* ${FOLDER_PATH}/library/pdf/samples/* ${FOLDER_PATH}/lang/[!e][!ns]_*
```

But it ends up making the unzipped directory contents as:

```
cs_CZ
el_GR
en_GB
es_ES
get-new-strings.sh
lang_check.php
lang_check.txt
language_list.txt
```

- Why is `cs_CZ`, `el_GR` and the files not matching that expression and being allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cs` and `el` both don't match `[!e][!ns]` pattern.

Unzip excludes all files that match pattern `[!e][!ns]_*`. To match this pattern file (or directory path) must satisfy following conditions:

- First symbol is not `e`
- Second symbol is not `n` or `s`
- Third symbol is `_` (underscore)

Only files that match all three requirements are excluded from unzip result. `cs_CZ`, for example matches only first and third.

**UPDATE (solution proposal):** Ugly solution that may work is exclude with 3 patterns. 
Assuming that all of the folders are in the root of zip file:

```
unzip -q ${ZIP_FILE} -x [!e]?* ?[!ns]* ??[!_]*
```

**UPDATE 2 (relative paths):** This one should work:

```
unzip -q ${ZIP_FILE} -x ${FOLDER_PATH}/documentation/* ${FOLDER_PATH}/library/pdf/help/* ${FOLDER_PATH}/library/pdf/samples/* ${FOLDER_PATH}/lang/[!e]?* ${FOLDER_PATH}/lang/?[!ns]* ${FOLDER_PATH}/lang/??[!_]*
```

Note that this will leave all files and folders starting with `en_` or `es_` in `${FOLDER_PATH}/lang` directory.

Comment: Well that makes sense. So should I use the curly brace syntax and just match the names directly like `/lang/{!en_GB,es_ES}`? Not sure if that is the correct syntax for negative string matching.

Comment: @crypticツ As far as I understand unzip doesn't support curly braces.

Comment: Would it be easier for me to just allow the entire folder to unzip and then do a rm command to remove all non-string matching entries? That way it should support curly braces AFAIK.

Comment: Are you sure? [Works on my machine](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html)

Comment: All my folders are not in root of zip folder. I tried `${FOLDER_PATH}/lang/"[!e]?_*" "?[!ns]_*" "*.*"` and it works, but still allows `el_GR`, forgive me if I am doing this wrong.